# Correlation matrix from VAR(1) model

Tags: covariance-matrix, vector-autoregression, lags

I have implemented a simple VAR(1) model with gaussian noise and no bias to generate two dimensional data. When computinng the empirical covariance matrice (for lag 0) of of this signal, it is always very close to the covariance matrix of the noise.

But I do not understand why it is the case. I derivated the formula of the covariance matrixe $\Sigma_X$ at lag 0 as such:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Sigma_X&=\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1}X'_{t+1}]\\ &=\mathbb{E}[(AX_{t}+\epsilon_{t+1})(X'_{t}A'+\epsilon_{t+1}')] \\
&=\mathbb{E}[AX_{t}X'_{t}A'+\epsilon_{t+1}\epsilon_{t+1}'+AX_{t}\epsilon_{t+1}'+\epsilon_{t+1}X'_{t}A'] \\
&=\mathbb{E}[AX_{t}X'_{t}A']+\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_{t+1}\epsilon_{t+1}']+\mathbb{E}[AX_{t}\epsilon_{t+1}']+ \mathbb{E}[\epsilon_{t+1}X_{t}'A']\\
&=A\Sigma_X A'+ \Sigma_{\epsilon}+\mathbb{E}[AX_{t}]\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_{t+1}']+\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_{t+1}]\mathbb{E}[X_{t}'A']\\
&=A\Sigma_X A'+ \Sigma_{\epsilon}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Following this result $\Sigma_X$ and $\Sigma_{\epsilon}$ have no reason to be equal in general. Can anyone tell me where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my error : the expression of $\Sigma_X$ as stated is good, the problem was in the code of my implementation.